# How to INSERT multiple VALUES using @parameter in spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I want to do a query that inserts multiple values in spanner, but I don't know how to do it using @parameter.

I want to execute the following query

```
INSERT Singers (SingerId, FirstName, LastName) VALUES
  (12, 'Melissa', 'Garcia'), 
  (13, 'Russell', 'Morales'), 
  (14, 'Jacqueline', 'Long'), 
  (15, 'Dylan', 'Shaw')",
```

How can I implement the following python code to use it?

```
def insert_singers(transaction):
    dml="""
        INSERT Singers (SingerId, FirstName, LastName) VALUES
          @singers
    """

    row_ct = transaction.execute_update(
        dml,
        params={"singers":???},
        param_types=???
    )
```

Comment: Please review this  thread, [Insert data into Spanner with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103807/insert-data-into-spanner-with-parameters?rq=1). 
Is the reference to the [Using STRUCT objects as bound parameters in SQL queries](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/structs#modifying_data_with_dml) answering your question?

Comment: I can insert single raw using STRUCT. But I can't insert multiple raw.

Comment: You should be able to do this by following this [batch operations sample](https://github.com/googleapis/python-spanner/blob/master/samples/samples/batch_sample.py)